# how to multiply two doubles

Tags: java, android, double, multiplication

I am working on an currency converter android application in which I am trying to multiply a double with another double value but after multiplying I am not getting the correct value. i also tried BigDecimal and still didn't get the correct amount. What would be best way to multiply doubles?

```
second_amount = Double.parseDouble(second.getText().toString());
                first_amount = Double.parseDouble(first.getText().toString());
                result = first_amount * second_amount;
                second.setText("" + df.format(result));
```

after using BigDecimal

```
                second_amount = Double.parseDouble();
                bdf = new BigDecimal(second.getText().toString());
                //first_amount = Double.parseDouble(first.getText().toString());
                bds = new BigDecimal(second.getText().toString());
                BigDecimal bdr = bdf.multiply(bds);
                //result = first_amount * second_amount;
                second.setText("" + bdr);
```

Comment: You're getting the correct doubles.  What you don't understand is how doubles work.  Doubles are not infinite precision, and they do not store decimal numbers.  They store binary numbers-  powers of 2 and 1/2.  So a simple fraction like .3 won't store exactly in a double.

Comment: What are you getting instead of the correct value? I should say you are doing the multiplication correctly.

Comment: @OleV.V.  if I am multiplying 1.9062 with 100 I am getting 1910.00

Comment: Most likely you have not run the code exactly as it stands in the question. Using your first method I get 190.61999999999998. There are typos in your second example, and I cannot guess exactly what you did.

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing something like currency calculations, where exact representation of short decimal fractions matters, it is best not to involve double at all. Pass the original string representation of the number directly to the BigDecimal constructor, and do your arithmetic in BigDecimal.

For example, `new BigDecimal("0.1")` has the value 0.1, but `new BigDecimal(0.1)` has the very slightly different value 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625, due to rounding on the conversion of the literal to double.